# SQL - complex pivot - Take several rows of data and condense into one with no unique key between rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my data

```
ID  LotNo       AlarmDateTime       AlarmMessage
1   1       1/1/2014 12:00      E-Stop
2   1       1/1/2014 12:02      Safety Door Opened
3   1       1/1/2014 12:05      Robot Fault
4   3       1/2/2014 5:09       Operator Door Opened
5   3       1/2/2014 6:00       Feeder Empty
6   5       1/4/2014 14:00      Feeder Jam
```

What I want Out is this:

```
LotNo,Alm_1_DT,Alm_1_MS,Alm_2_DT,Alm_2_ms,Alm_3_dt,Alm_3_ms
1, 1/1/2014 12:00, E-Stop, 1/1/2014 12:02, Safety Door Opened, 1/1/2014 12:05, Robot Fault
3, 1/2/2014 5:09, Operator Door Opened, 1/2/2014 6:00, Feeder Empty, NULL, NULL
5, 1/4/2014 14:00, Feeder Jam, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

I have spent several days looking into this problem, I know I could solve it with a stored procedure and save it to a table, but it would be system intensive. I am hoping that there is a way to use a select statement and build a view.

Thank you for your time

The Doc.

Comment: Is there an upper limit to the number of rows per lotNo?

Comment: no, there is no limit as the system can generate lots of alarms,

Comment: but I am only interested in displaying the top 5 by date

Comment: The term you'll want to look-up is pivot (unpivot in this case)...it's the act of turning many rows into columns and vice versa. you'll have a bit of an interesting implementation from the top 5 component, but theory is the same.  I'm not going to have time to tailor you a code response now...perhaps tomorrow if you haven't figured it out on your own.

Comment: I have been playing with unpivot, and while this looks to give me something I can use, I haven't figured out how to pivot the resulting data into the format I need, I think I need a column that has a count up, 1-2-3-4 ect. related to the each row in the unpivoted data reset upon a new lot, then I can use it to pivot the data into the format I want.

Comment: Edit your question to include what code you have so far and we'll use that as a starting point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Twelfth for you advice, this provided the first part of the solution, the second part of the solution was when I discovered that I could reset the row_number() command using partition (solution was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407615/auto-increment-field-that-resets-after-a-change-in-another-field)), with these 2 items I was able to build a data set that I could pivot and get the desired output.

```
select [Conveyor_ID], [1] as Alarm_1_1, [2] as Alarm_1_2, [3] as Alarm_2_1, [4] as Alarm_2_2, [5] as Alarm_3_1, 
                      [6] as Alarm_3_2, [7] as Alarm_4_1, [8] as Alarm_4_2, [9] as Alarm_5_1, [10] as Alarm_5_2
From
(
    select [Conveyor_ID], Data, row_Number() over (partition by [conveyor_ID] order by getdate() ) as IndexNum
    from (Select top 100 percent [Conveyor_ID], cast([Alarm_Message] as varchar(60)) as [Alarm_Message], cast([Alarm_datetime] as varchar(60)) as [Alarm_datetime] 
          from [Database].[dbo].[tabel]
          order by [conveyor_ID], [Report_Alarm_ID] asc) RA
    unpivot (Data for Type in ([Alarm_datetime], [Alarm_Message])) as upvt
) as TB1
pivot
(
max([data])
for [IndexNum] in ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10] )
)as Pvt2
```

here is the raw data from the tabel:

```
Conveyor_ID Alarm_Message   Alarm_datetime
0           PLC Loss Of Comm                                                2008-08-04 14:14:40.000
0           PLC Loss Of Comm                                                2008-08-04 13:55:54.000
0           PLC Loss Of Comm                                                2008-08-04 13:52:25.000
0           Oven Temp High Alarm                                            2008-08-04 13:10:20.000
0           E-stop Active                                                   2008-08-04 10:52:05.000
0           Oven Temp Low Alarm                                             2008-08-01 19:38:37.000
0           E-stop Active                                                   2008-08-01 10:19:01.000                                         2008-07-30 15:12:53.000
```

Here is the data unpivoted with the index field added

```
Conveyor_ID Data                   IndexNum
0           Aug  4 2008  2:14PM    1
0           PLC Loss Of Comm       2
0           Aug  4 2008  1:55PM    3
0           PLC Loss Of Comm       4
0           Aug  4 2008  1:52PM    5
0           PLC Loss Of Comm       6
0           Aug  4 2008  1:10PM    7
0           Oven Temp High Alarm   8
0           Aug  4 2008 10:52AM    9
0           E-stop Active          10
0           Aug  1 2008  7:38PM    11
```

Finally, Here is the result:

```
Conveyor_ID Alarm_1_1           Alarm_1_2                 Alarm_2_1             Alarm_2_2               Alarm_3_1            Alarm_3_2                  Alarm_4_1             Alarm_4_2                Alarm_5_1            Alarm_5_2
0           Aug  4 2008  2:14PM PLC Loss Of Comm          Aug  4 2008  1:55PM   PLC Loss Of Comm        Aug  4 2008  1:52PM  PLC Loss Of Comm           Aug  4 2008  1:10PM   Oven Temp High Alarm     Aug  4 2008 10:52AM  E-stop Active                                               
1           Jan  3 2009  6:58AM Low Bearing Air Fault     NULL                  NULL                    NULL                 NULL                       NULL                  NULL                     NULL                 NULL
```

again, I would like to thank Twelfth for his quick response and his help in finding the first part of my solution. I have not tried to optimize this in any way, and any suggestions or improvements are more than welcome.

The Doc.