# Auto-increment field that resets after a change in another column MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, partitioning

Can you provide a very simple MYSQL example of how to create a "count" or "order" field that would auto-increment, but restart after every change in a different field? In the table below, the "Order" field would restart at "1" every time there was a change in the "Meal" field. Thanks.

> **Meal      Time     Order**
>
> Lunch     10:30      1
>
> Lunch     11:00      2
>
> Lunch     11:15      3
>
> Dinner     4:30      1
>
> Dinner     4:45      2
>
> Dinner     5:00      3
>
> Dinner     5:30      4

Comment: can you please be more specific..? Your description make confusions.

Comment: i couldn't understand your table, can you describe it more clear please? you may find your answer here, http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html

Comment: what i want to do in MYSQL, works on microsoft sql server with this statement: 

select row_number() over (partition by Meal order by Time) , * from YourTable

Comment: My problem is doing this in mySQL

Comment: check this link to better understand the problem. it has a solution but i can't replicate it on mysql
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407615/auto-increment-field-that-resets-after-a-change-in-another-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The auto-increment is always per table, you cannot make it specific to some column or index.

If you want to have per-column auto-increment id, you will need to do it manually. I.e. when inserting new item, select maximum of the id via `select MAX(id) FROM ... WHERE name = 'Dinner'` and then insert the `maximum+1`.

To do this in Select statement in some report you need to implement it via session variables and case statement.  See [this tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/).

Comment: what i want to do in MYSQL, works on microsoft sql server with this statement: 


select row_number() over (partition by Meal order by Time) , * from YourTable

Comment: my problem is doing this on mysql

Comment: @Manuel Morgado : I was unclear from original question. See updated answer, there is very clear example in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

The feature is available in the MyISAM engine, but not in InnoDB.  It can be simulated.  See [MyISAM to InnoDB](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) and search for 'abc'.  Here is the gist of it:

```
  BEGIN;
  SELECT @id := IFNULL(MAX(id),0) + 1 FROM foo WHERE other = 123 FOR UPDATE;
  INSERT INTO foo
     (other, id, ...)
     VALUES
     (123, @id, ...);
  COMMIT;
```